# "__pad2" this member of the linux struct "ip_options" work for what?

Tags: c, linux, networking, linux-kernel

learned the ip_options struct from the linux kernel and want to do some modification for my program.

```
struct ip_options {
    __be32      faddr;
    unsigned char   optlen;
    unsigned char   srr;
    unsigned char   rr;
    unsigned char   ts;
    unsigned char   is_strictroute:1,
        srr_is_hit:1,
        is_changed:1,
        rr_needaddr:1,
        ts_needtime:1,
        ts_needaddr:1;
    unsigned char   router_alert;
    unsigned char   cipso;
    unsigned char   __pad2;  
    unsigned char   __data[0];
};
```

can I just ignore the member `__pad2`?

PS: `__pad2` just do padding for the `struct`, but how many size of the `struct` should be aliag (my own comprehension)

Comment: Just count the bytes.

Comment: `__pad2` is used to ensure `__data` is aligned on a 4/8-byte boundary. Since this looks like a variable-length struct, it's probably necessary to ensure `__data` is aligned the same way `struct ip_options` is.